# Determine the location of a project's .sim directory via the Ocean API?

Tags: ocean, petrel

Within a Petrel plugin, I wish to determine the location of the current project's .sim directory, if it has one. Is there an Ocean API call I can use to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this directory from a simulation case object using the following method(s):

```
Case simCase = aSimulationCaseFromSomewhere;
string exportPath = EclipseFormatSimulator.GetArguments(simCase).CaseInfo.ExportPath;
```

Good luck!

Gaute

Comment: That works, thanks. However, before I mark it as the correct answer, I have a supplementary question: there appear to be three well known simulators supported by the API: ECLIPSE100, ECLIPSE300 and FrontSim. I assume EclipseFormatSimulator.GetArguments(... will work fine for the first two, but what about the last one?

Comment: This should work all fine with a FrontSim case as well (all well known simulators are Eclipse format - and behave similarly)! A case defined by a custom simulator - an implementation of EclipseFormatSimulator - might have an export behavior different from the "native" simulators though. The ExportPath will still be valid, but it's up to the plugged-in simulator to decide whether it exports Eclipse style decks and whether it uses the ExportPath directory for anything at all really...

Answer (score 1):

Yes this mechanism will work independent of whether your Simulation.Case is from one of the WellKnown simulators (E100, E300, FrontSim) or a Plug-in simulator based on the EclipseFormatSimulator class.

James.